# Why is getParameterTypes empty when called on a controller Method?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

If I have an instance of a controller method, obtained by calling getMethod on the Class object for a controller, why does the method, which is defined as taking 1 parameter, have an empty array for "getParameterTypes"?

Is there any way to actually get the parameter types it accepts?

Comment: Hmm, it has the action annotation when I filter the list of methods by annotation. I wasn't aware it was viewed differently, though, I thought it was still a "method," just with an annotation.

Is there a way to view an action's parameters?

Comment: did you pass any value to the params of action method? @Zachary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a controller action which accepts any parameters the Grails compiler generates a corresponding no-argument method.

```
class MyController {
    // you write an action like this...
    def someAction(String name, Integer age) {
        // your code here
    }

    // the Grails compiler generates this additional method...
    def someAction() {
        // do some stuff needed by the framework

        // ...

        // initialize parameters

        def name = ...
        def age = ...

        // call the original method
        someAction(name, age)
    }
}
```

I expect that you are calling getParameterTypes on the method that the Grails compiler generated and not the original method.

Comment: what does "the Grails compiler" do if you define an action method that doesn't have any params.

Comment: There is no need to define an additional method in that case.  It adds the additional code to the method that you defined.

Answer (score 0):

Is your action a closure or a method? If it's a closure, I wouldn't expect it to work with the `Method` class from the reflection API. I tested the following method-action from one of my own controllers

```
class MyController {

  def someAction(MyCommand command) {

  }
}
```

and it behaves as expected

```
Method action = MyController.methods.find( it.name == 'someAction' }
assert [MyCommand] == action.parameterTypes as List
```

Comment: The OP explicitly states "controller method".